# Latest upto date Selenium guides

Tags: ruby, selenium

I've been looking into setting up a Selenium test suite recently but all of the documentation on Selenium I find is quite fragmented.

Does anyone had found any good books or blogs on using Selenium Grid with ruby that could be of use to me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try below links :

http://www.jroller.com/selenium/entry/selenium_overview_tutorial

http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/01_introducing_selenium.html